# How can I implement JWT(JSON Web token) for SOAP web service?

Tags: security, soap, jwt

I want to implement JWT for my SOAP webservice. Basically , what I want to achieve is to having basic JWT security across SOAP webservice request HTTP header. My project is built as EAR and contains couple of SOAP webservices without any authentication. Can someone help with the step by step approach for the same , I tried referring few resources online but all where related to rest web services , am not sure if its a good idea to implement JWT for SOAP webservices.
Any leads are appreciated.

Comment: did you find it?

Comment: Hi @Mohammed Ali,I actually wrote a unix script to encode-decode using JWT API and then embed this script in my web server lib, also while calling soap api, i put this autogenerated token in soap header and then decode and validate it. This is kinda not so appropriate but worked for our requirement. Its been more than 2 years , might be now market have got the support for the same.

Comment: I converted my SOAP web service to JSON REST web service, and dumped the SOAP thing :P

Comment: Wisest decision! I must say :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application you may have to use `WS-Security` or not.

But in any case, you can still use JWT:s to let the client authenticate and possibly provide scopes for authorisation. JWT is just a signed key with embedded state information, as long as you can pass it from the client to the server, it can be used. You can send it as a cookie (typically from browser clients) or in a header (typically the Authorization header), but you can basically do it whatever way that works for your application. You can even put it as an XML element of your request SOAP body, but probably no one would encourage you to do that.

Make sure you can keep the JWT secure on the client, not reachable by other applications (processes/threads) or other web applications (javascripts running in other tabs/windows). If it's stolen from the client, any other actor can use it to authenticate.

#### 1

So firstly, decide how the client should obtain the JWT. It could be a self hosted service where a secret or some biometrics are provided to prove authenticity, or it can be a hosted service like Auth0. Any system where you can exchange something personal for a JWT.

#### 2

Secondly decide how your web application will verify the incoming JWT:s. It basically needs to fetch the public key and verify the signature using the algorithm you chose, like `RS256` or similar. You need some sort of API Gateway where you intercept all calls and can block them if the JWT does not fulfil your needs. Investigate your web ervice to find the right point in the stack for verification.

#### 3

Finally, at https://jwt.io/ you can both find libraries to help you with the signature verification, and you can use it to create JWT:s with a test key of yours. Do this to build your web application and test the authentication part. Same thing goes for when you develop your client, once it obtains a JWT, you can test it at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to ensure that it's properly signed.

Note that the JWT itself is in JSON format under the hood (it's also base64 encoded), but that does not prevent your payload body to be XML encoded.